# can we use for loop without condition?

Tags: c, for-loop

My question is simple,thus I will not go in deep

can we use `for()` loop without condition like this

```
for(;;space+=1)
{
printf("  ");
break;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: unconditional breaks in loops aren't too useful :)

Comment: @InternetAussie I had programmed that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course you can. An empty condition is taken to evaluate to `1`.

`for (;;){/*ToDo - your code here*/}` is idiomatic C.

Comment: Sorry for not including in my question but is this applied to other loops to??(like do-while and while loop)

Comment: `while(1){}` or `do {}while(1);`

Comment: No, they require *expressions* (rather than optional expressions). Folk will write `1` explicitly to achieve the same effect.

Comment: It seems 'while(1){}' is a more cleaner approach to this than using for loop with missing conditions. (since both do the same) Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** it is perfectly correct to do so.

But since you have provided a break immediately after printf, it will only execute once. I'm not sure whether this is what you wanted. But if so, then this works fine.

Comment: Thanks it helped me